# How can I query both the post and category using 'foreach' for a custom menu in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Please forgive me I'm learning PHP and Wordpress.  I'm trying to create a dropdown menu in wordpress, and have each category as the menu options, and the titles of each post in that category as submenu.  I have the categories showing up properly, but for I can't figure out how to only get that particular categories post to show up under the right category.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'talent');
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach (get_categories('hide_empty=0&exclude=1') as $category){
    echo "<li class='has-children'><a href='#'>";
    echo $category->name;
    echo "</a><ul class='is-hidden'>";
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo "<li><a href='#0'>";
    echo the_title() ;
    echo "</a></li>";
    endwhile; 
    else: endif;
    echo wp_reset_query();
    echo "</ul></li>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  :-

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'talent');
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach (get_categories('hide_empty=0&exclude=1') as $category){
echo "<li class='has-children'><a href='#'>";
echo $category->name;
echo "</a><ul class='is-hidden'>";
$args = array( 'category' => get_cat_ID($category->name), 'post_type' => 'talent' ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args );    
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
?>  
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   
<?php endforeach; ?> 
echo wp_reset_query();
echo "</ul></li>";
}
```

Above foreach will give you posts from that particular category. Then you can customize it as per your requirements. Hope it will sort out the issue.

Comment: hmmm, unfortunately that still puts every entry for "Talent" under every category...

Comment: Can you echo $category->id and see if you are getting cat_id from it or not?

Comment: You can check this link..
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/how-to-show-all-posts-of-the-category-in-wordpress

Comment: Try this.. $category_id = get_cat_ID($category->name); and then use this variable as cat_id.

Comment: sorry, where would I put that and what would i be replacing?   i'm so sorry!  i'm going crazy trying to wrap my head around this

Comment: $args = array( 'category' => get_cat_ID($category->name), 'post_type' =>  'talent' );
try this code on above $args array

Comment: Great to hear that my first answer on Stackoverflow helped someone:)

Answer (score 0):

$args = array('post_type' => 'talent','cat'  => array(48,43,49,46,47,44,51,50,42));

you can get post according to specific category just by adding cat in your array and number of categories u want to show

Comment: thank you, not sure if i was clear though.  I'd like to category to be the menu, and the entries to be the submenu without having to code each category.  so ideally, if I add a new category, it would show up on the menu.  and if i add new entries to any category it would show up on the appropriate  submenu,

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, with this method I would need to have a different array per category?